# What would be the result of the following query?

Tags: sql

[image]

The following query I tried...

```
select d.deptID, max(tt.total)
from dept d,
(select d.deptID, d.deptName, sum(days) as total
from vacation v, employee e, dept d
where v.empId = e.empID
and d.deptID = e.deptID
group by d.deptID, d.deptName) tt
where d.deptID = tt.deptID
group by d.deptName;
--having  max(tt.total);
```

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using limit since your inner query already does the calculation.

```
select TOP 1 * from (
select d.deptID, d.deptName, sum(days) as total
from vacation v, employee e, dept d
where v.empId = e.empID
and d.deptID = e.deptID
group by d.deptID, d.deptName)
order by total desc;
```

Depends on the dbms you're using.. this is for mysql

In oracle use where rownum = 1

In sql server use SELECT TOP 1 *

Comment: If you use SQL Server, replace `select * from ... limit 1` with `select top 1 * from ...`

Comment: @anonymous which dbms are you using?

Comment: OK. Got it. spelling mistake.   `select top 1 * from 
( select d.departmentid, d.departmentname, sum(days) as total 
from vacations v, employee e, department d 
where v.employeeid = e.employeeid and d.departmentid = e.departmentid 
group by d.departmentid, d.departmentname) tt
order by total desc;`

Comment: Why doesn't it work with ORDER BY placed in the inner query?

Comment: -Order by doesn't work in subqueries. 
-You need to add "With ties" (see my answer), as this query does only return one line, even when there are many departments sharing the same maximum of vacation days.

Answer (score 1):

Using Top:

```
Select top 1 with ties * from
(Select D.DepartmentName, sum(V.Days) as SumDays
from Vacations V
inner join Employee E on E.EmployeeID=V.EmployeeID
inner join Department D on D.DepartmentID=E.DepartmentID
group by D.DepartmentName)SumDays
Order by SumDays desc
```

Comment: As @sagi said, it will depend on your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
   SELECT TOP 1 d.departmentname,
             Sum(v.days) AS vacations
FROM   employee emp
       INNER JOIN department d
               ON d.departmentid = emp.departmentid
       INNER JOIN vacations v
               ON v.employeeid = emp.employeeid
GROUP  BY d.departmentname
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 d.departmentname,
             Sum(v.days) AS vacations
FROM   employee emp
       INNER JOIN department d
               ON d.departmentid = emp.departmentid
       INNER JOIN vacations v
               ON v.employeeid = emp.employeeid
GROUP  BY d.departmentid, d.departmentname
ORDER  BY 2 DESC`

Comment: @anonymous: I have updated my answer. Please check now